# Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I am using Aws Cognito User Pool and its various service for my asp net core application

I have added one Aws Toolkit to do all the api call for development purpose and added one profile as a default but when I deploy that project and did some operation

```
Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service
```

I got this exception ..!

I know there is some credential issue but what is the best way to manage credential when we deploy the application...?

Suggestion Needed

Thanks

Comment: Confirm that you have assigned an IAM Role to the Amazon EC2 instance. The role needs to have the necessary permissions to allow your app to call AWS services.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but actual problems come after we publish the code

Comment: I am confused. Is the error message coming from an Amazon EC2 instance, or from your own computer? Please add more details to your question.

Comment: Okay so here it is 

After going through some documents I found that this type of error comes whenever we call aws api without passing credentials like access key or secret key..

Comment: Is the software reporting that error running on an Amazon EC2 instance, or on own computer?

Comment: I clearly mention

When we call Aws Api in our local what I do is create profile in Aws Explorer so it woks fine for me but when i publish the code the api does not work so then I found out that the actual problem is in credentials @JohnRotenstein

Comment: Does this mean that you have resolved your issue?

Comment: Yes @JohnRotenstein 

Thanks for your help

I want to conclude with one solution if it can help others

When we publish our code to azure app service for the better security we should have to store our access key and secret key in azure key vault and take whenever it is required.